# npgsql Connection string and server compatibility mode

Tags: npgsql

We recently had to roll back NpgSql to version 2.2.5 in a data access library for compatibility between data syncs and Amazon. I now have another app using a method in the same library the is setting "Server Compatibility Mode=Redshift" and generating this error:

> "key=value argument incorrect in ConnectionString" & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: server compatibility mode"

```
Dim connstring As String = [String].Format("Server={0};Database={1};" + "UID={2};PWD={3};Port={4};Sslmode=Disable;Pooling={5};MaxPoolSize=10;Server Compatibility Mode=Redshift", Server, DBName, MasterUsername, MasterUserPassword, Port, Pooling)
```

I could not find when this parameter was added in release notes going back, unless there is another issue here I need to find when this was introduced?

Answer (score 0):

The `Server compatibility mode` parameter was added in Npgsql 3.0. If you need to go back to 2.2.5 you'll need to remove it.

2.2.5 is extremely outdated by now and is no longer being maintained. If there's anything preventing you from using 3.x please file an issue.

Comment: Owch, that's a bummer because NHibernate uses 2.2.7 :(
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/lib/teamcity/postgresql/Npgsql.dll
I'm still gonna play around this this some more, see if there's any work around but it sounds like NHibernate will not support redshift currently.